# vertical-align: middle misalligns normal text and a

Tags: html, css

So I have some text with a link in a table, which I'm trying to align vertically:

```css
* {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Shoul be <a href="https://www.google.com">aligned</a> vertically
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Multiple</div>
      <div>lines</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>Could be </span><a href="https://www.google.com">aligned</a><span> with spans</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But as you can see, the first "aligned" isn't aligned with the rest of the text (or maybe the other way around).
The only fix I could find was to wrap all text in `span`s, but is there a way to do it without all the extra `span`s?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to not use `*` because you will apply `vertical-align` to everything when you only need it on the `td` element.

```css
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Should be <a href="https://www.google.com">aligned</a> vertically
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Multiple</div>
      <div>lines</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>Could be </span><a href="https://www.google.com">aligned</a><span> with spans</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The issue is that when having `a` with `span` all of them will get aligned the same thus they will be at the same position but when you align the `a` inside a text you will move it slightly from the `baseline` (default alignment) to the `middle` which create the issue.

If you align only the `a` and not the `span` you will have the same issue as the first case like shown below.

Hover to notice how the border will get misaligned

```css
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

span,a {
 border:1px solid;
}

table:hover a {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Shoul be <a href="https://www.google.com">aligned</a> vertically
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Multiple</div>
      <div>lines</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>Could be </span><a href="https://www.google.com">aligned</a><span> with spans</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Applying `vertical-align` to any and all elements doesn't make any sense, particularly since many elements will ignore it. It will also (at least theoretically) have a negative impact on performance when it comes to CSS rendering.

Instead, apply it specifically to `td`s.

```
td { vertical-align: middle; }
```