# Why is vertical-align applied to the other element?

Tags: css

I wrote CSS with `vertical-align` applied to one of these boxes.

Then, `vertical-align`, which is specified for only one side, is applied to the other element.

```css
.a {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: red;
}

.a,
.b {
  display: inline-block;
}

.a {
  vertical-align: middle; /* vertical-align applied to .a also affects .b */
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b">
  <p>texttttt</p>
</div>
```

Why does setting the `vertical-align` on one side affect the other side?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635716/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/54379729/8620333

Comment: ............. ^ The first one is almost a duplicate if not an exact duplicate

Answer (score 0):

vertical align for inline elements works for aligning inline elements based on each other as your example says `a` will be centered in the middle with the element `b` not based to their parents height.

if you want to align `b` vertically based on `a` position you have to add a vertical align property to `b`

```
.b{
  vertical-align: top;

}
```

for a side note to see a proper results and understand it better you should reset the default margins on the p tag

```
p{
  margin:0;
}
```